# manually make jQuery dialog check if resize is needed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autoresize

I have a jQuery dialog that loads its content trough ajax after its opened.

See this [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/editedredx/A4zhr/) (content is not loaded trough ajax but added after open, which is enough to demonstrate my problem).

html:

```
<div id="test">test</div>
```

js:

```
$("#test").dialog({
    minHeight:100,
    maxHeight:200,
    width:300,
    open: function(){
        $(this).html("test<br /><br />test<br />" +
                     "<br />test<br /><br />test" +
                     "<br /><br />test<br /><br />" +
                     "test<br /><br />test<br />" +
                     "<br />test<br /><br />test");
    }
});
```

When it is opened it does not stay true to its `maxHeight` until you resize the dialog. Is there some sort of `resize` method I can call after I added content to the dialog?

I prefer not to have to manually figure out if a resize is needed and how high since its pretty much already built into the ui plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/editedredx/BPhcf/) example.

Not exactly the elegant solution I hoped for but so far it seems to work.

If anybody has a better solution I'll be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the html code in an actual div on the webapge, then use dialog on that div. 
Or to change height (and other options) after init ... from [jquery docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) :

```
//getter
var width = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "height" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "height", 460 );
```

Comment: I know that works, but I want to be able to alter the content after the dialog has opened.

Comment: @NimChimpsky I know how to manually set the height, but how can i know what height i should set it to?

Comment: @red-x, I thought you wanted it set to your maxheight, which was not working as required ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky I want it set to its new content, but not less than minHeight or more than maxHeight.so if the contentheight is somewhat between min and max height the dialog height should not be either min or max height.

Comment: @red-x first put the content in a div and get the height of that div, then perform your checks and set dialog height

Comment: @NimChimpsky problem was that i was looking for an elegant solution, since its already built into the ui plugin i thought i might be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the maxHeight in the open function seems to do the trick:

```
$("#test").dialog({
    minHeight:100,
    width:300,
    open: function(){
        $(this).html("test<br /><br />test<br /><br />test<br /><br />test<br /><br />test<br /><br />test<br /><br />test<br /><br />test<br /><br />test");
        $(this).parent().css("height", "auto");
        $(this).css("maxHeight", 200);
    }
});
```

EDIT: It appears when the 'test' div is used as a dialog it becomes nested within the dialog div along with a header div. As a result both the test div and its containing div need to have their heights set with the containing div taking into account the height of the dialog header div. Setting its height to auto should take care of this.

Comment: Problem is that the bottom content is just gone than, the scrollbar does not appear anymore.